# SSRS report showing different data when ran twice

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I received a report from a customer that the data from an SSRS report is sometimes changing between two runs. I have confirmed that the only application we have that connects to that database is only able to insert, there are no updates in the code for that application. That being the case, my only next hope was to have an audit or trace set up to track what queries are actually being sent to the SQL Server.

They are on SQL Server 2008R2. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated as we don't have direct access to the SQL Server to troubleshoot.

Comment: Did you receive an example of the differences?

Comment: It is possible for a query to return different results on the same data. For example, if you use a `Top(N)` statement with no sort order. Would you please share the SQL?

Comment: The same goes for the aggregate function `First()` or `Last()`. Without any sort order they will return different results in your tablix.